Packet Drop. MTU Mismatch in the given network
Following is the Structure of Network along with MTUs on the interface (on which connection is made)
We can assume that connection is bidirectional.



Now, we are getting RX packet drop on Server C.
However, there aren't any overruns.
On Server E, there are NO TX/RX packet drops.
Can MTU Mismatch be the potential reason of Packet Drop? If yes, can anyone provide detail what case potentially was there which caused drops? And what on interface packet must have been dropped?
Case

If RX Packet is larger than MTU, it should be fragmented.
If RX Packet is smaller than MTU, then no issue should be there.

Why does MTU then cause packet drop?

Moreover, assuming E never sends packet to C, then still are there any chances of packet drop?

Edit: Analysis involving what will happen if MTU

on A and B is less than 1500
on A and B is greater than 1500
on A is greater than 1500, and on B is less than 1500
on B is greater than 1500, and on A is less than 1500

will help in understanding.

As per my understanding, packet should be fragmented.
Any help would be appreciated.

You are confusing the terminology. What a device gets off the wire is a layer-2 frame, not a packet. A layer-3 packet is the payload of a layer-2 frame. Layer-2 ethernet has no fragmentation, ethernet will just silently drop a frame larger than allowed on an interface. IP, at layer-3, may be able to fragment a packet that the layer-2 protocol sends it from its payload, as long as the DF (Do Not Fragment) flag is not set in the packet header, and many things today do set that flag.

Thanks for the insights @RonMaupin. Any specific resource to learn more about the same?

Unfortunately, resource recommendations are explicitly off-topic here.

Also, understand that questions about hosts/servers are explicitly off-topic here.

The question wasn't about hosts/server @RonMaupin. It was more about network/MTU. The scenario of server/switch was created to better explain the question. I don't think this question should be closed.

Careful: the MTU is an interface property, not a host property. A host may use the same MTU on all its interfaces but not necessarily so.
Your diagram indicates two networks, one shared between C and E with mixed MTU settings, and one shared between A and C with unknown MTU settings.
Your diagram also shows a problem in understanding: "1500" is most likely the true MTU for the network layer on C (standard for Ethernet), while "9214" is probably the maximum frame size for E on that interface. The difference between both is the L2 overhead (14/18/22 bytes for Ethernet w/o FCS/with FCS/with FCS and Q tag).

Now, we are getting RX packet drop on Server C.

That is to be expected. Host E can send frames exceeding C's MTU setting, causing it to drop them.

If RX Packet is larger than MTU, it should be fragmented

No. There is no fragmentation for the data link layer/L2. Also, fragmentation even on the network layer needs to happen before sending a packet, it never happens on reception.

assuming D never sends packet to C, then still are there any chances of packet drop?

A switch never sends frames on its own behalf (ignoring management functions).

Thanks for the reply, @Zac67. Have edited the question to include a follow-up. Can you please help with it?

Same thing: when a frame exceeds an interface's maximum frame size that interface drops the frame - same with hosts or switches actually.

Alright @Zac67. There is RX packet drop on C, but no TX packet drop on E. Can MTU still be reason for the same? If yes, why TX packet drop wasn't recorded on E?

Why should there be a TX frame drop on E? It has no idea that there might be a problem downstream.
